# CSS modifications not apply

Tags: html, css

I've created a simple web page using HTML and code shows below

```css
#header_1 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link href="_css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="header_1">This is My Html</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I've double checked that my link to style.css is correct. But this style not apply at least once. I've used google chrome browser.

Comment: I updated your question and pasted your code into a snippet, which shows that it seems to work fine.

Comment: clear cache and try again

Comment: check console if any errors

Comment: The path seems to contain an underscore. Check the path

Comment: /css/style.css or ../css/style.css might work depending on your folder structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes this happens because the browser caches the CSS file. To reload the new version of the CSS file, you have to hard refresh your browser. To do that, press **CTRL + F5**.